# Select rows from a DataFrame based on logical test in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

Consider this dataframe

```
my_input_df = pd.DataFrame({
'export_services': [[1],[],[2,4,5],[4,6]], 
'import_services': [[],[4,5,6,7],[],[]], 
'seaport':['china','mexico','africa','europe'], 
'price_of_fish':['100','150','200','250'],
'price_of_ham':['10','10','20','20']})
```

And I want to do a filter on the export_services that is boolean (discards empty lists) and output only a subset of columns

```
my_output_df = pd.DataFrame({
'export_services': [[1],[2,4,5],[4,6]], 
'seaport':['china','africa','europe'], 
'price_of_fish':['100','200','250']})
```

How would I go about this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert column to boolean, what return `False`s for empty values, so is possible use `loc` for filtering:

```
df = my_input_df.loc[my_input_df['export_services'].astype(bool), 
                     ['export_services','seaport','price_of_fish']]
print (df)
  export_services seaport price_of_fish
0             [1]   china           100
2       [2, 4, 5]  africa           200
3          [4, 6]  europe           250
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `str.len`

```
my_input_df.loc[my_input_df.export_services.str.len()>0,].drop(['import_services','price_of_ham'],1)
Out[220]: 
  export_services price_of_fish seaport
0             [1]           100   china
2       [2, 4, 5]           200  africa
3          [4, 6]           250  europe
```